# How to write Joins in loop in SQL server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I have a below kind of data in my table and i need to get the below kind of output.

```
U.Id  Current_Id  Previous_Id Date reason
01        aa          null     21   xyz
01        bb           aa      24   yxz
01        cc           bb      24   out
01        dd           cc      25   tot
01        aaa         null     11   yyz
01        bbb         aaa      12   zyy
```

First four records are one set and next two records are one set. we can identify this by current_id and Previous_ID columns. I need below kind of Output.

Output :

```
O1 - aa - 21 - 25 - tot
01 - aaa - 11 - 12 -zyy
```

For each set i need first and last record dates. How can i achieve this in ms sql?

Comment: Most likely you need need to combine Top and Min functions with a group by. Your questions isn't very clear though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive Common Table Expression (rCTE) to recurse through the data, and then get the respective `MIN` and `MAX`:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('01','aa',NULL,21),
                ('01','bb','aa',24),
                ('01','cc','bb',24),
                ('01','dd','cc',25),
                ('01','aaa',NULL,11),
                ('01','bbb','aaa',12))V([U.Id],Current_Id,Previous_Id,[Date])), --A column with a . in the name is a bad idea.
                                                                               --Date is an odd name for something that is clearly an int
--Solution
rCTe AS(
    SELECT YT.[U.Id],
           YT.Current_Id,
           YT.Previous_Id,
           YT.[Date],
           YT.Current_Id AS Start_Id
    FROM YourTable YT
    WHERE Previous_ID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YT.[U.Id],
           YT.Current_Id,
           YT.Previous_Id,
           YT.[Date],
           r.Start_Id
    FROM YourTable YT
         JOIN rCTE r ON YT.Previous_Id = r.Current_Id)
SELECT r.[U.Id],
       r.Start_Id AS Current_Id,
       MIN(r.[Date]) AS StartDate,
       MAX(r.[Date]) AS EndDate
FROM rCTE r
GROUP BY r.[U.Id],
         r.Start_Id;
```